# how do you reverse the sign of elements in an axis of a numpy array

Tags: numpy

Is there any way to reverse the sign (postive=negative, negative=positive) of each individual element of a numpy array without iterating through the array?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to multiple your numpy array with `-1`.

For example:

```py
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,-1,-2,-3,-4])
print(data)
>> array([1,2,3,4,-1,-2,-3,-4])
data = data * -1
print(data)
>> array([-1,-2,-3,-4, 1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the axis you want and mutliply it by -1.

Exemple :

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,-2],[-3,4]])
arr[0,:] = arr[0,:] *-1
```